# Refused to connect local ip address by using docker while running ok without docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

[Editted]

I am trying to dockerize a simple flask project. I kept getting this error when I run the project using docker. On the other hand the project works just fine when I run it normally using python3 test-flask.py

Docker File

```
FROM python:3.9.6-slim

# https://www.lifewithpython.com/2021/05/python-docker-env-vars.html
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONUTF8=1 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    curl \
    wget \
    unzip \
    jq \
    ffmpeg \
    libsndfile1-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.10.2%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl" \
    && pip install torch-1.10.2+cpu-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl

RUN mkdir app

WORKDIR /app

COPY README.md .
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY setup.py .
COPY src ./src
RUN pip install .

# COPY main.py .
COPY test_flask.py .

CMD [ "python", "test_flask.py", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  asr-cpu-local:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./data:/data
    - ./models:/models
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:8000:8000
```

In the Terminal and Docker Container log, after I run it with docker, it shows no error at all

```
* Serving Flask app 'test_flask' (lazy loading)

* Environment: production

  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.

  Use a production WSGI server instead.

* Debug mode: on

* Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

* Restarting with stat
```

For additional information, I have run docker port to check, but the error still occured:

```
docker port <container-name>
8000/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:8000
```

For the File test_flask.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import librosa
from src.jrasr.predictors import Wav2vec2bert2bertPredictor


MODEL_CONFIG = {
    "name": "Wav2vec2bert2bertPredictor",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "models": [
        {
            "name": "wav2vec2",
            "dir": "/models/wav2vec2-base-csj-kana-v0.0.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "bert2bert",
            "dir": "/models/bert2bert-csj-kana-v0.0.1"
        }
    ]
}


@app.before_first_request
def load_model_to_app():
    # Load the model
    app.predictor = Wav2vec2bert2bertPredictor(MODEL_CONFIG)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "This is Home Page"

@app.route('/data/<audio_path>')
def predict(audio_path):
    model = app.predictor
    audio_path = "/data/"+audio_path
    data, _ = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=16000, mono=True, duration=10)
    words = model.predict(data)
    result = "".join(words)
    return result
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, debug=True)
```

But when I try to access the Ip address as shown in the Terminal and Docker Container Log, I got that 127.0.0.1 refuse to connect such as in the image shown below. The problem is in the terminal and docker log, there isn't any Error message, but still I can't access it, can anyone tell me, how to solve my problems?

[Error at the local browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHMYf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the `localhost` interface and when running inside the container only the container has access to it. To be accessible outside the container it should be the special IP `0.0.0.0` to bind all interfaces.

### Solution 1

Change the host to be `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` in the `test_flask.py`. Something like the following snippet.

**WARNING:** As `0.0.0.0` binds all interfaces to the outside world it could be a security risk if running it locally instead of in a container. That said, the **Solution 2** is the recommended one (With the `127.0.0.1` in the Python source as it is). So, when running it directly locally it binds to the `localhost` and when running it in the container it binds the outside world of the container itself.

```py
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True)
```

### Solution 2

On the other hand, to run it passing the host as an argument the `Dockerfile` should be changed to the following:

```
...

ENV FLASK_APP=test_flask
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Test it with the browser connecting to `http://localhost:8000/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: Thank for your answer, right now I have changed the docker-compose.yaml to port 8000, and also checking the flask using port 8000, but still the error to access the 127.0.0.1:8000 was still occured, with exact same error which is: 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data, and also after checking debug log at terminal and docker still there isn't any error log

Comment: Would you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72933716/edit) your question and copy-paste the `test_flask.py` into it.

Comment: I have done it sir, thank you for your help and consideration for your help

Comment: I've changed the answer with this new info. Please take a look

Comment: Thank you sir, the Solution 1 work well, May I know why we need to set it to "host = 0.0.0.0" ?

Comment: The problem is that `127.0.0.1` is the localhost interface and when running inside the container only the container has access to it. To be accessible outside the container it should be the special IP `0.0.0.0` to bind all interfaces.